# json redundant data retrieved

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$('.editBtn').click(function(){//EDIT BUTTON EVENT
        $.getJSON('edit.php?url='+encodeURI($(this).siblings('a').attr('id'))+'&action=edit',function(data){
           $.each(data, function(key, val) {
               alert(key+': '+val);
            });
        });
    });//EDIT BUTTON END
```

and here is php part in question:

```
elseif($_GET['action']=='edit'){
$output=$mysql->getDb()->query("select * from video
    where url='{$_GET['url']}'")->fetchAll();
header("content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($output[0]);
}
```

what happens is that upon clicking `.editBtn` button alert pops up `0:value0, 1:value1,...` and then goes again but in a way that i only want it to be `name0:value0, name1:value1,...`

what is going on?

p.s. php run independently:

`{"url":"www.vimeo.com\/20721308","0":"www.vimeo.com\/20721308","title":"Dis-patch Festival R.I.P.","1":"Dis-patch Festival R.I.P.","description":"Sadly, the last goodbyes to the Dis-patch Festival Belgrade edition in this tribute \"R.I.P.\" video collage. The end is always the beginning...","2":"Sadly, the last goodbyes to the Dis-patch Festival Belgrade edition in this tribute \"R.I.P.\" video collage. The end is always the beginning...","country":"serbia","3":"serbia","postDate":"2011-05-07 05:56:04","4":"2011-05-07 05:56:04","views":null,"5":null}`

Comment: can you run edit.php independently and paste the output here?

Comment: So you're saying it's running through and alerting everything twice?  It all seems right.  Maybe you're attaching the click handler twice?  Do you have it posted somewhere that we can see it in action?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. what i meant is that i don't want `number:value` to appear, but instead only `title:value`. made it work through Jobsz's nice tip. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure of the format being returned here.. Usually framework SQL objects return the data set in it's own object format.. You probably want to pass the SQL data into an array object, and then json_encode the array back to your client.

```
$returnData = array(
    'name' => $output[0]->name,
    'videopath' => $output[1]->videopath 
);

echo json_encode(array('success'=>1, 'data'=>$returnData));
```

Comment: No problemo -- keep an eye out for your primitive data types versus data types native to your framework -- often they will not be compatible with other languages. I also suggest when dealing with ajax in using a success data key to handle responses :)

Comment: please if you have any article/discussion to refer me to, i would be happy to read.

Comment: I wish I could give you something but it's just based off my own experience. Just try to think of ajax calls as a handshaking event with your client-server. You want to make sure it's safe to take what the server's giving you, use an identifier if the data is safe (not null, etc), perhaps an error message along with it.

Comment: thanks, i will for sure have to read up more on jquery ajax api.